# faster way to do grep -v in python

Tags: python, grep

i have two list , 
`a = ["1","3","4","22","2"]` and
`b = ["1","2"]`

is there a way to get the output `c = ["3","4"]` in python, just like

```
grep -vf b a
```

in bash if you have file a

```
1
3
4
22
2
```

and b

```
1
2
```

i cannot using grep , and i tried this , but it takes a long time if the list is big , is there a way to do it faster in python ?

```
c = []
d = []

for i in b:
    for j in a:
        if i in j:
                d.append(j)       
c = list(set(a).difference(d))
```

is there a way to do it faster in python ?

Comment: Why 22 is not included in the result?

Comment: apologies , what i mean is

c = list(set(a).difference(d))

Comment: Both `i` and `j` are integer numbers. The expression `i in j` cannot be calculated. Your question is unclear. Please explain why 22 is not in  `c`.

Comment: thanks again, you are right , its unclear , i've edited my question , i hope i make the question more clear

Answer (score 1):

One way using `list-comprehension`:

```
c = [i for i in a if not any(j in b for j in i)]
print (c)
#['3', '4']
```